# How can I install the Android SDK system-wide?

Tags: software-installation, system, android-studio, android-sdk

My school offers 3GB for each student's home folder. Installing the Android SDK fills up almost half of that.

I'm wondering if it would be possible for the IT people to somehow install the Android SDK system-wide. I understand that this is not a use case with first-class support from the Android people.

Comment: Its possible but any updates will have to done by the `system admin`.  It would be dropped in say the system lib for all to access.

Answer (score 3):

Your IT person can install the SDK into the `/opt` folder.  For instance:

```
/opt/android/android-version/
```

The /android-version will be the specific location of the android installtion.  A directory listing of that would be (for instance):

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 ljames ljames 4096 Nov  5 10:04 temp
drwxrwxr-x  7 ljames ljames 4096 Nov  5 09:54 system-images
drwxrwxr-x  7 ljames ljames 4096 Nov  5 08:36 platforms
drwxrwxr-x  5 ljames ljames 4096 Nov  5 08:35 platform-tools
drwxrwxr-x 12 ljames ljames 4096 Nov  5 08:35 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 ljames ljames   16 Sep 26 15:29 .knownPackages
drwxrwxr-x 11 ljames ljames 4096 Sep 26 13:24 tools
drwxrwxr-x 25 ljames ljames 4096 Sep 26 13:24 docs
drwxrwxrwx  3 root   root   4096 Aug 16 21:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x 11 ljames ljames 4096 Jul 30 19:59 build-tools
drwxrwxr-x  6 ljames ljames 4096 Jul  6 17:20 add-ons
drwxrwxr-x  5 ljames ljames 4096 Jul  6 16:29 sources
drwxrwxr-x  4 ljames ljames 4096 Jul  5 05:17 extras
-rw-rw-r--  1 ljames ljames 1158 Oct 13  2015 SDK Readme.txt
```

Each user can access/link to is by typing this from their commandline:

```
ln -s /opt/android/android-version ~/android-sdk
```

Of course as George mentioned in his comment, only the IP person (or someone given sufficient permission by the IT person) can perform the updates.